# Music for Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell series?

Tags: music, jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell

**Who composed the music for the ongoing BBC TV series *Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell*?**

Watching the series, I kept being reminded of the music in *Wolf Hall*, so I wanted to find out if they were by the same composer. I've tried researching it online, but with no luck. Maybe I'm not looking in the right places...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IMDB credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2548418/fullcredits) two composers for this series:

- [Benoît Charest](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0152844/)
- [Benoît Groulx](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1014920/)

Music credit for [Wolf Hall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3556920/fullcredits) is given to [Debbie Wiseman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0006341/).

Comment: Thanks! I'd had a look at IMDb, but somehow missed this info. Have a checkmark.